# Using "are/is" after a list with "and/or"

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions, verb-agreement, disjunction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Singular or plural following a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/singular-or-plural-following-a-list)

> James and Mark are going to help you.

Here, I use 'are' because the subject is plural.

> James or Mark are going to help you.
>
> James or Mark is going to help you.

Here, I’m not sure whether to use 'are' or 'is' because the subject isn't plural(?) It’s one or the other – so does that mean the subject is still plural, and I should use 'are', or is 'is' correct here?

Comment: ...and/or [Singular or plural noun in a sentence after using both in a related conjunction?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12628/singular-or-plural-noun-in-a-sentence-after-using-both-in-a-related-conjunction)

Comment: I think most of would simply sidestep your specific problem by saying *"James or Mark **will** help you"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of your sentences is a compound sentence; that is, each is composed of two sentences reduced to one:

> James **is going** to help you **and** Mark **is going** to help you => James **and** Mark **are going** to help you.

The conjunction *and* makes the subject a plural subject: *James and Mark*, two guys, are going to help you.

> (Either [Implied but optional]) James **is going** to help you **or** Mark **is going** to help you => James **or** Mark **are going** to help you.

The conjunction *or* makes the subject a singular subject: *James or Mark*, only one of the two guys, is going to help you. I don't know which, but both won't.

You can always avoid the problem by changing the verb from *is going to* to *will*:

> James **and** Mark **will** help you.
>   (Either [Implied but optional]) James **or** Mark **will** help you.

Comment: 'The conjunction or makes the subject a singular subject' so it should be 'James or Mark ''is'' going to help you', right?

Comment: I got confused by the answer as well, which one is it after all?

Comment: This answer is confusing

Comment: "(James or Mark) is going to help you." ⇒ "James is going to help you or Mark is going to help you." But it does not sound very idiomatic.