# "Changing and improving are not always the same thing" or "Changing and improving is not always the same thing"

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions, conjugation

Are both valid? I think the first is the only option, but I have been challenged on this and I can't explain exactly why the second is wrong. It does make sense, I suppose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it: My apples and orange are/is wrong?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15769/is-it-my-apples-and-orange-are-is-wrong)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using "are/is" after a list with "and/or"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94054/using-are-is-after-a-list-with-and-or)

Answer (score 5):

If you use *is*, then you are implicitly treating the compound noun *changing and improving* as a single, grouped set.  Which makes the sentence have the form **X is not the same thing**, which naturally leads to the question "X is not the same thing as WHAT?"

Clearly the intention is for you to compare *changing* to *improving*, so they are really two separate items; and therefore you need to use the plural *are* to make it clear that you are comparing them, individually, to each other.

Comment: Yes - contrast _Tom and Jerry were always fighting_ with _Tom and Jerry was my dad's favourite cartoon_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Though that's more a matter of threating a plural as a singular because it's a title. Comparable: *Cats are always fighting* and *Cats is my mum's favourite musical*, respectively.

Comment: @Jon Hanna - I'd say it's more fundamentally treating a singular concept, whether the corresponding noun appears in singular or plural form, as a construct requiring singular agreement. Plays, books, shows etc would be one subset of such concepts - but so would composites (_fish and chips is my favourite meal_) and collectives considered as wholes (_the team was founded in 1896_ - contrast _the team were all tired after the match_, with notional concord).

Answer (score 1):

Mismatches in grammatical number are tricky, and have no perfect solution that will meet with total agreement.

This though is not an example of that. Your sentence is of the structure:

> [noun phrase] [third person simple present tense of *to be*] not always the same thing [elided "as each other"].

The third person simple present tense of *to be* will be either singular or plural depending on the grammatical number of the noun phrase.

The noun phrase "Changing and improving" is a plural noun phrase formed from two singular nouns joined by *and*.

So the correct form of the sentence is:

> Changing and improving are not always the same thing.

We don't match the verb to the word before it, we match it to the phrase before it. The phrase is plural, and so must the verb be.