# Controversy over verb choice in "neither you nor I {is/am/are} in control"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, ambiguity, verb-agreement, disjunction

I was watching the film *A Game of Shadows* starring Robert Downey Junior and Jude Law when this line came up, "**...neither you nor I is** in control..." (I can’t remember the exact words that ended the phrase; if anyone can supply them, it would be much appreciated.)

It immediately struck me as being odd. When I mentioned this to my boyfriend; an English native speaker, with a PhD in something sciency, he told me it was correct. When I asked why, he couldn't explain but put forward the following sentence as an example. "Neither of us *is* in control..." However, I disagreed with the wording and said the sentence should have been: "Neither **one** of us *is* in control..." The genderless third person, *one*, is singular, and hence, so too the verb that follows. And we say, "one is" NOT "one are".

> "Neither you **nor I are** in control over ..."

I believe the above *sounds* better, but it is more *logical* to say:

> "Neither you **nor I am** in control..."

because the verb agrees with the subject closest to it; however, I'm not sure if I have ever read or heard this solution. So, I tried inverting the subject and auxiliary verb order and the resulting phrase was:

- "Neither you **nor am I** in control..."

which sounds very formal, pompous, and ... odd. Am I imagining things?

The two subjects *you* and *I* are two separate individuals who are not joined together, I agree the verb should be in the singular; but why should we use "is"? We don't say, "you is" or "I is". Before anyone rushes off to claim my question is a duplicate of a previous Stackexchange one: ["Neither Michael nor Albert is correct" or "Neither Michael nor Albert are correct"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/neither-michael-nor-albert-is-correct-or-neither-michael-nor-albert-are-corre) I want to explain why the answer to that question fails to explain why my boyfriend and the film makers consider the  sentence below correct:

> Neither you nor I **is** in control...

As I see it, *Michael* and *Albert* are two separate individuals, it therefore stands to reason that the verb should be singular, and "is" agrees with the subject. If I rephrase the *neither* and *nor* construction, I would get:

> - *Michael **is not** correct but neither **is** Albert*
>     OR
> - Michael **is not** correct and Albert **isn't** either.

Which have the same meaning, (*either* being the negative equivalent of *neither*) the sentences are grammatical which leads me to conclude that the verb must be singular and hence

> - Neither Michael nor Albert **is** correct

However, when I rephrase the "*neither you nor I*" sentence following the same procedure I *have to* say this:

> - You **are not** in control but neither **am I** (‘I am’ is ungrammatical)
>     OR
> - You **are not** in control and **I’m not** either.

which leads me to surmise that the sentence below must be grammatically correct

> - Neither you nor I **am** in control"

So, why does my boyfriend insist that the sentence ought to be:

> Neither you nor **I is** in control

Which one of us is right and *why*?

Comment: See discussion here, especially the comments: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/which-is-correct-neither-is-or-neither-are

Comment: I don't quite follow your argument at the end of your second paragraph. Your BF says "Neither of us *is* ..." You think it should be "Neither *one* of us *is* ..." - So you are *in agreement* on the verb form. Hence I'm not clear what the next 2 sentences are referring to, when you still conclude that "is" is correct. I have a recollection of reading in another Q. that with joint subjects, each of which requires a different verb form, then the subject nearer the verb dictates the verb form. OTOH, that would require *am* in your orig.quote! Or is the subject simply "Neither", which takes "is"?

Comment: I cannot really get into the grammatical details of your example, but I don't see anything wrong with it. I don't see anything wrong with the one you suggested either.

Comment: See [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/122935).  It is hard to make *is* be "correct" without modification, but as @TrevorD points out, it is easy to do so with minor modification. The bottom line is that native speakers fumble around here, and that you will not get a unanimous answer from them.

Comment: @tchrist As I said "I had a recollection of reading it" - I just didn't realise the recollection was that recent! Thanks.

Comment: @TrevorD I think my point about specifying the third person pronoun in, *neither **one** of us*  makes it easier to see why the verb has to be "is", whereas when the subject is "I" the verb has to be "am". Thus the phrase logically speaking ought to be "neither you nor I am" (is that clearer, now?).

Comment: My BF used the example of "neither of us is in control" as a way to back up his argument. I don't think that it has any relevance to the *neither you nor I (be)" phrase.

Comment: Please see also [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/68235). There's lots more where that comes from. People keep asking it. Nothing is ever closed as a dup.  As ELP sang, *"Welcome back my friends to the show that never ends / We're so glad you could attend / Come inside! Come inside!"*.

Comment: BF and I have been arguing over this. He still insists that "is" is the correct verb form because we say: "*neither one of us is*" and, according to him, "**us**" is the equivalent of saying "**you and/nor I**" Grrrr..! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Just in case you and your boyfriend still have the occasional argument over this, you can tell him that your logic is correct and his is incorrect. “Neither of us is” is structurally entirely different from “Neither you nor I”: in the former, _neither_ is a singular third-person person, so the verb is _is_ without a doubt; in the latter, _neither_ is a conjunction (of sorts), so it really doesn’t directly affect verbal agreement. That doesn’t necessarily mean he’s wrong about what form to use, but it does mean that his parallel is _not_ parallel.

Comment: If you wish to convince him further, you can illustrate by how “Neither you nor I is” = “Neither of us is” (to him), but “Neither the Americans nor the French _are_” ≠ “Neither of them is”. (I presume he doesn’t say “neither of them are”—though this is very common in general—if he feels “neither of us are” is wrong.)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613727/2085).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When subjects are connected with *neither/nor*, the one closest to the verb controls the agreement. Thus, *neither you nor I **am***. Why? [Because lots of English grammar books say so](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22neither+you+nor+I+am%22+grammar).

Sounds awkward? It does. [Lots of other English grammar books agree](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22neither+you+nor+I+are%22+grammar) and so does [actual usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Neither+you+nor+I+are%2C+Neither+you+nor+I+am&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). As you can see, there's an actual controversy here. There are workarounds that would please adherents of both viewpoints. The easiest one is probably *neither I nor you **are***, but most of your proposed variations would work.

Of course *"*Neither you nor I **is**"* is totally wrong, because *is* doesn't agree with anything in this phrase.

Comment: I pretty much agree, but the last sentence seems a bit extreme. *Nothing* is entirely satisfactory, but there are plenty of written instances of [neither you nor I **is**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22neither+you+nor+I+is%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). It's certainly no worse than Shakespeare's [Thou and I **am** one](https://web.duke.edu/rpc/performance/thouandiamone.html)

Comment: @FumbleFingers We have examples of disjunct "or thou art", too, as in [*One legion of wild thoughts, whose wandering wings / 
 Now float above thy darkness, and now rest /
 Where that or thou art no unbidden guest, / 
 In the still cave of the witch Poesy,*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/68240). People keep asking about disjunctive subjects. I keep writing about it. Nothing is ever closed as a dupe, and they keep coming and coming and coming and coming and coming.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, perhaps there's some kind of poetic license in force here.

Comment: @tchrist: I'd have probably closevoted as a dup myself when I read and upticked your first comment, except I realised *you* hadn't closevoted. Guessing that meant you saw some difference here, I thought I'd wait a while.

Comment: @ n.m.: My guess is that since there simply *isn't* a "definitively correct" approach to this one, we're all indulging in a bit of poetic license here, however we try to phrase such constructions.

Comment: According to Google Ngrams, the [actual usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neither+you+nor+I+am%2Cneither+you+nor+I+are%2Cneither+you+nor+I+is&year_start=1740&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=) over the last 250 years seems to heavily favor "are".

Comment: @PeterShor which kind of confirms my affirmation that "neither you nor I are" sounds better, I wonder why that is. Is it due to familiarity? Interesting the Ngram results for [AmEng](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Neither+you+nor+I+am%2CNeither+you+nor+I+are&year_start=1850&year_end=2005&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) and [BrEng](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Neither+you+nor+I+am%2CNeither+you+nor+I+are%2CNeither+of+us+are%2C+Neither+of+us+is&year_start=1850&year_end=2005&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) including "Neither of us are" vs "is".

Comment: Please give actual examples from the books you point generally to. I'm finding that it's difficult to pin them down; one just seemed to disappear mid-C&P. But there seem to be counterexamples even at first sight.

Answer (score 1):

As a non-native speaker I don't feel competent for this kind of question. Reading the post and the answers I see this grammar problem really is a grey area. I would tend to accept the solution "am", but was interested  what Ngrams says about the use in reality. Astonishingly the most frequently used verb form is "are". Follows "is", and the least frequent use is "am".

So this problem has two aspects, one is what grammars say, and we see that grammars can't solve the problem 100 per cent, except providing a mechanical rule. The other aspect is what writers use in reality.

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Neither%20you%20nor%20I%20am%2C%20Neither%20you%20nor%20I%20is%2C%20Neither%20you%20nor%20I%20are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNeither%20you%20nor%20I%20am%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNeither%20you%20nor%20I%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNeither%20you%20nor%20I%20are%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: '[O]ne is what grammars say' wrongly gives the impression that all grammarians are agreed on correct practice here. And 'what writers use in reality' is similarly too broad-brush. The bottom line is that there is divided usage, no consensus.