# Noun-verb agreement for a list of singular nouns including "I" and joined by "or"

Tags: verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions, disjunction, compound-subjects, grammatical-person

I understand that when you have a list of singular nouns joined by "or", you should use a singular verb.

Example:

> Either Chris or Len is the next player

But what verb do you use if one of the items in the list is "I"?

> Either Justine or I is the next player

or

> Either Justine or I am the next player

or something else?

Comment: Answered (by tchrist) (& John Lawler) at [Singular or plural verb after a series connected by "or" ](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122876/singular-or-plural-verb-after-a-series-connected-by-or).

Comment: The question cited as a duplicate involves plural and singular nouns connected by "or," whereas the question here asks about third-person and foirst-person nouns/pronouns connected by "or." Consequently I don't think this question is a true duplicate.