# With which noun should a verb following "(person) or I" agree?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, personal-pronouns, coordinating-conjunctions, disjunction

In the sentence below, should the bolded word be *prepare* or *prepares*?

> When my family eats at home, my mom or I **prepares** the meal.

Normally, I would side with the verb agreeing with its corresponding noun in the sentence. However, since this is an exclusive *or*, where it's either *my mom* or *I* doing the preparation, that means that it would be *my mom prepares* or *I prepare*.

I'd like to avoid writing it like the sentence below, as it just sounds a bit awkward.

> When my family eats at home, one of either my mom or me prepares the meal.

I was unable to find any existing questions that covered my scenario exactly. Most deal with *(person) and I* or the order of the two verbs in the sentence.

How can I write this using the *my mom or I* syntax?

Comment: @sumelic Good point. Crafted a better title and nuked the [tenses] tag.

Comment: @sumelic No problem, thank you! I'm not familiar with the tagging on this site. :)

Comment: I think the following questions are related and might be helpful: [Controversy over verb choice in “neither you nor I {is/am/are} in control”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122969), [Which of several or’d-together subjects should the verb agree with?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104976)

Comment: @sumelic Those are indeed helpful and I believe the first one actually answers it: "*the one closest to the verb controls the agreement*", which would make *prepare* correct. (This seems to agree with [Grammar Book](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp).) Feel free to propose an answer or mark as a duplicate.

Comment: You go with which pronoun is closer to the verb,   so in this case *my mom or I prepare the meal*. Cf Quirk et al.

Answer (score 2):

The bolded word should be **prepare**.

> When my family eats at home, my mom or I **prepare** the meal.

The rule is: If a compound subject contains *or* or *nor*, the verb should agree with the part of the subject that is nearer the verb.

Comment: Can you cite a reference that supports this rule?

Comment: There are many grammar references out there; here's one: http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp

Comment: I think it might be useful to give a caveat, as that source does: "This rule can lead to bumps in the road. For example, if I is one of two (or more) subjects, it could lead to this odd sentence: *Awkward: Neither she, my friends, nor I am going to the festival.* If possible, it's best to reword such grammatically correct but awkward sentences."

Comment: eh, I don't think that sentence is so awkward, depending on where it's used.  But I didn't want to get into personal preference and style here; I just wanted to give the actual rule.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting. I think I would get round it by writing "my mom prepares the meal or I do".

Answer (score -3):

"When my family eats at home, *either* my mom or I prepares the meal."
The *prepare* is correct, add *either* instead.

Comment: But then you have "I prepares," which looks like an incorrect verb agreement with "I".

Comment: Instead of 'I prepares', it should look like 'either my mom or I" and 'prepares the meal'