# Singular vs plural: the effect of conjunctions

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, conjunctions, rules

Consider:

- Please check that the username and password is correct.
- Please check that the username and password are correct.

If I had to break the statement into its parts:

- Please check that the username *is* correct.
- Please check that the password *is* correct.

I feel that *username and password* can be seen as a single noun and therefore the correct form is *is*. Based on [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/12630/87168) answer, I'm confused: *the number of the verb is determined by the number of the verb's subject*. Is *username* the subject or object?

Can someone please advise?

---

This question was marked as a duplicate but the duplicate tagged isn't quite related. Rather, based on @user2370114 response, this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15769/is-it-my-apples-and-orange-are-is-wrong/15770#15770) is a better match. Furthermore, it doesn't address my concern about the subject vs object distinction (as answered by @RegDwigнt♦).

To summarize:

- If you are speaking of multiple things, and even if both were singular, the copula (verb of being) would still be plural.
- Both `username` and `password` are the subject. Interestingly, in my use here, `are` felt more natural :)

---

So can I rather ask: is there ever a time when items can be seen as a single subject and therefore take the singular form of the verb?

Comment: The conjunction is not part of the question. The question would be identical without "Please check that".

Comment: Lenin is correct. Lenin and Stalin are correct. And yes, when Lenin is correct, or when X is correct, or when X is Y, then X is the [subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_%28grammar%29).

Comment: @user2370114 The conjunction being talked about here is 'and'; 'that' is often labelled a complementiser nowadays.

Comment: @user2370114 has a good point. If I ignore the use of `that`, then I had a list of two items: 'The username and password are correct'. Then this answer indicates that `are` is the correct form: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/15770/87168

Comment: @RegDwigнt I was rather confused when I first read your comment but I see you were giving examples. Thank you for answering my question about the subject :)